# Optimize mongoDB query to get count of items from separate collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections namely "tags" and "bookmarks".

```
Tags documents: 

        {
            "taggedBookmarksCount": 2,
            "taggedNotesCount": 0,
            "_id": "627a80e6b12b0dc78b3a6d4b",
            "name": "Article"
        },
        {
            "taggedBookmarksCount": 0,
            "taggedNotesCount": 0,
            "_id": "62797885b479b5906ef6ed43",
            "name": "Client"
        },

Bookmark Documents:

{
            "_id": "627a814db12b0dc78b3a6d54",

            "bookmarkTags": [
                {
                    "tagId": "627a814db12b0dc78b3a6d55",
                    "tag": "Article"
                },
                {
                    "tagId": "627a814db12b0dc78b3a6d56",
                    "tag": "to be read"
                }
            ],
            "bookmarkTitle": "Please sorrow of work",
  
           
        }
```

Objective is to get the counts of bookmarks for all the tags in the "tags" collection.

Below is my current implementation, which returns the count of bookmarks for each tags.But this query takes around 3 sec to run (REST API response time) for 20 tags.

```
        tags = await Tag.find(
          {
            userId: req.params.userId
          },
          { _id: 1 }
        );
        tagIds = tags.map(tag => {
          return tag._id.toString();
        });

    const tagCounts = await Promise.all(
      tagIds.map(async tagId => {
        const count = await Model.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              bookmarkTags: {
                $elemMatch: {
                  tagId: tagId
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: '_id',
              count: {
                $sum: 1
              }
            }
          }
        ]);
        return { tagId, count: count[0] ? count[0].count : 0 };
      })
    );
```

I am assuming its taking longer as I am mapping over all the tags, there are multiple round trips to database.Please suggest an approach to reduce the time of query execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below

```
db.bookmark.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$bookmarkTags" //Reshape tags
  },
  {
    "$lookup": { //Do a join
      "from": "tags",
      "localField": "bookmarkTags.tagId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "btags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": { //reshape the array elements
      path: "$btags",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { // Group tag wise bookmarks
      "_id": "$bookmarkTags.tagId",
      "docs": {
        "$addToSet": "$btags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { //Get counts, project what you want.
      tag_id: "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$size": "$docs"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hziepnb3dFC)

If you have given list of tag ids, then you can use it in match stage.

[Updated playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JxYLOea28BZ)

```
db.bookmark.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$bookmarkTags"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tags",
      "localField": "bookmarkTags.tagId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "btags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$btags",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$btags._id",
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$btags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      tag_id: "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$size": "$docs"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hi..Gibbs thank you for your time..I was trying playground for the data i am getting count of tags present in bookmarks..Can you pls help me understand how to get count of bookmarks for tags in tags collection

Comment: Can you add a sample playground and expected o/p?

Comment: Hi Gibbs. Please refer this link for the data. https://mongoplayground.net/p/1U108V4l8Ub

Comment: Expected Output: [
  {
    "count": 3,
    "tag_id": "627a80e6b12b0dc78b3a6d4b"
  },
  {
    "count": 1,
    "tag_id": "62797885b479b5906ef6ed43"
  }
]

Comment: Check the edit and let me know @sgrmhdk

Comment: Also you mentioned that to get count by array of tagIds, we need to pass it as array in match stage..Can you please help me understand how to tweak this query for that use cae

Comment: `{$match: {tag_id: {$in: ['a', 'n']}}}` Try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244967/discussion-between-sgrmhdk-and-gibbs).

Comment: Hi Gibbs, sorry but I am new to mongo DB. Can you please help me understand, where shall I put match part of the query

Comment: [Refer this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kZuW7u6kk1v)

Comment: Thank you Gibbs..Will learn more about different mongo DB operators..